# IncludeFilter multiple levels not working

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

Having problems with this IncludeFilter and including multiple levels.  I'm using Entity Framework 6 Plus.

This is the example they provide https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter under the `Load multiple levels` heading.

This works, but it returns more warranty records than I want.

```
db.Application.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == applicationId)
    .Include(x => x.Lienholder)
    .Include(x => x.Warranty.Select(y => y.Coverage.CoverageGroup))
    .Include(x => x.Vehicle)
    .Include(x => x.Vendor)
    .First();
```

This works but `.Coverage` is null, but it's the closest one to the example.

```
db.Application.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == applicationId)
    .Include(x => x.Lienholder)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z => true).Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    )
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z => true).Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    ).Select(y => y.Coverage.CoverageGroup))
    .Include(x => x.Vehicle)
    .Include(x => x.Vendor)
    .First();
```

This doesn't work at all because apparently with `IncludeFilter` you have to include a where clause

```
db.Application.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == applicationId)
    .Include(x => x.Lienholder)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z => true).Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    ).Select(y => y.Coverage.CoverageGroup))
    .Include(x => x.Vehicle)
    .Include(x => x.Vendor)
    .First();
```

This one works but it doesn't eager load Coverage

```
db.Application.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == applicationId)
    .Include(x => x.Lienholder)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z => true).Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    )
    .Include(x => x.Vehicle)
    .Include(x => x.Vendor)
    .First();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You cannot mix `Include` with `IncludeFilter` or `IncludeOptimized`.
- You need to include every path once in his own `IncludeFilter`

In your closest example, you missed to include "Y.Coverage"

Those are currently limitation of the library.

Here is what you are looking for:

```
db.Application.Where(x => x.ApplicationId == applicationId)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Lienholder)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    ))
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z => true).Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    ).Select(y => y.Coverage))
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Warranty.Where(z => true).Where(z =>
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 2 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 3 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 8 ||
        z.WarrantyStatusId == 10
    ).Select(y => y.Coverage.CoverageGroup)))
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Vehicle)
    .IncludeFilter(x => x.Vendor)
    .First();
```

> This doesn't work at all because apparently with IncludeFilter you have to include a where clause

No, you don't have.

Comment: This is correct except there is a bracket imbalance that I can't fix because apparently I need more than six characters.  Maybe an admin can fix it?